# Why are "homework questions" redundant?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises

I have already two questions *[on-hold](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243050/is-there-conservation-of-momentum-if-theres-conservation-of-energy)* and *[closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238663/does-the-kinetic-energy-change-depending-on-the-direction-of-the-velocity)* because they were considered as homework questions.

I think these people are exaggerating. Who told these people that my questions were about homework questions?

In addition, resolving homework questions leave doubts and often misunderstandings. Therefore if a person does a general question it should be accepted.

Furthermore, why can't this Questions and Answers site be like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)? There is ton of homework questions and they are not taken unacceptable.

Are there misunderstandings? I would want to know what were my mistakes in my questions so I can do better questions that will be more *on-topic*.

Comment: Have you actually read the homework policy the close reason links to? If yes, what about that is unclear to you?

Comment: You're much more likely to get an honest attempt to help you improve your questions (ie. the last paragraph) if you remove the seemingly-angry rant from the middle. The people you think are exaggerating are also the ones who would be on the Meta site to help users understand and work within the policies. But as ACuriousMind said -- if you read the policy, you'll see that "homework" encompasses more than questions literally assigned by an instructor for a grade.

Comment: @tpg2114 I did and showed my effort and it wasn't a question about a real specific problem. I actually think I did the best I can.

Comment: @PichiWuana I didn't look at the questions so I'm not making any statements about that. I'm just giving you some friendly advice -- the people who vote to close things are also the ones who do the majority of things here on Meta, so keeping a friendly and respectful tone (even if you don't genuinely feel that way) will get a lot more positive feedback.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I would want to be clear why was my question put *[on-hold](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243050/is-there-conservation-of-momentum-if-theres-conservation-of-energy)*

Comment: For that one, I voted *unclear what you're asking* because you don't say why you see any connection between conservation of energy and conservation of momentum and because it's unclear from what you want to "prove" conservation of energy. If you're not given the information that a collision conserves energy, it won't, in general.

Comment: *"Why can't this Questions and Answers site be like Mathematics? There is ton of homework questions and they are not taken unacceptable."* - It can; simply convince all of those that volunteer their time here to answer questions that they'll enjoy answering the same homework like questions over and over and over and over again and that it is such a good use of their time that they'll vote to change the site's homework policy.

Comment: Math SE has turned into a garbage of HW, lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure of the two questions you link does seem a bit unkind and I've voted to reopen them, though I note that both got good answers before they were closed.

Just at the moment we are experiencing a flood of homework, poorly written and just plain lazy questions, and I suspect we are getting a little trigger happy with the close button.

Answer (score 1):

Questions that ask *How do I prove...* or *How do I calculate...*, as is the case for both of yours, will almost always get flagged for closure because it's a [homework-like question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange), defined *on this site* as,

> any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc.

Many of us spent several years in college and doctoral programs and we're really not interested in doing your work for you (as you can [see as you peruse this Meta.Physics.SE list of questions tagged *homework*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)), but we *are* interested in answering questions about tough concepts & clearing up your misunderstandings. So to prevent closure, consider what *specific physics concept* you are having troubles with and ask about that.

Comment: +1.Well said. I'm damn tired explaining newbies __we aren't Yahoo!__ : /

Comment: My questions were most about **misunderstandings** that I would want to get cleared specially **[this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243050/is-there-conservation-of-momentum-if-theres-conservation-of-energy)** one. I know I got answers but I would want to avoid closed and on-hold questions that I do.

Comment: If your question was about misunderstanding, then you've done a bad job showing it because you asked (effectively) how to calculate it. A good, on topic question will not be asking for computations but for explanations about something.

Comment: @KyleKanos The [question I refered to](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243050/is-there-conservation-of-momentum-if-theres-conservation-of-energy) in the last comment didn't.

Comment: Yet your question asks, *How do I **prove** this?*